# Using Firebase/Authenticattion to control access to a web page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having an issue when using Authenticattion with Firebase (using Password-Based Accounts) in Javascript.

I followed this document:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth
and things are working as I expect.

Here is my configuration and where I hit a problem.

I have a main web page (called *M.html*) which requires a login to be accessed.

I have a login page (called *L.html*) which is a gate to access the main page.

When a user goes to the login page, he needs to enter credentials to go further.
If he logs in he should access the main page.

If a user attempts to go directly to the main page, a check is performed to see his login status.
If he is logged in all should be fine, if he is not he should be forced back to the login page.

But what happen is that the main page never detects that the user is logged in and he is always brought back to the login page.

I need to know the procedure to follow to make the main page aware that a login has been accepted in the login page.

I have tried various options in my code but it did not work.
I also read that I may have to use *firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then....*
but did not find any way to make it work as it should.

To make things clear, I made simplified versions of the main an login pages.
Below is the code for both. I hope that someone can easily see where I should change the code to get the behavior I wish to have.

The *M.html* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="mainPage"></div>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase.
  var config = {
    apiKey: "myyKeyyy",
    authDomain: "......firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://......firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "....",
    storageBucket: "........appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "........."
  },
  app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script>
function checkUser() {
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {setMainPage();}
else {window.open("http://.../L.html",'_self');}
}


function setMainPage() {
let label = document.getElementById("mainPage");
label.innerHTML = "<h1>This is the main page!</h1><br/>";
label.innerHTML += "<h1>I can be here because I am logged in !!</h1>";
}

//setMainPage(); // This would show the contents without checking that a user is logged in.
checkUser();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The *L.html* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase.
  var config = {
    apiKey: "myyKeyyy",
    authDomain: "......firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://......firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "....",
    storageBucket: "........appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "........."
  },
  app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script>

firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  // Sign-out successful.
  console.log("Sign-out successful.");

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      window.open("http://.../M.html",'_self');
    }
  });

}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
  console.log("Sign-out error.");
});


function LogInProcess() {
let theEmail = document.getElementById("EmlAdr").value.trim(),
thePassword = document.getElementById("PsWd").value;

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(theEmail,thePassword).catch(function (error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log("errorCode: " + errorCode);
  console.log("errorMessage: " + errorMessage);
  // ...
});
}
</script>

Email address: <input type='text' name='EmlAdr' id='EmlAdr' value=''><br/><br/>
Password: <input type='password' name='PsWd' id='PsWd' value=''><br/><br/>
<input type='button' id='LgIn' style='font-size:20px' value='Log In' onClick='LogInProcess()'><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an `onAuthStateChanged` observer to check if the user is logged in. Otherwise you will often get the auth object in an incomplete state. Check the latest documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

Replace your `checkUser` function with this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // show your main content
  } else {
    // redirect to login
  }
})
```

Once the firebase app has initialized fully, this will trigger and you should have a user if one has successfully logged in.

Comment: But this is what I do in L.html, where the logging in is happening. Do you mean I should also do it in M.html too? Where it should already be done, in my understanding.

Comment: Yes. Well, I just tried and it works following your suggestion. That means things work slightly differently from what I had first imagined. I learned something. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Firebase is all async and event-based, so any code that works with the db needs to be inside a callback for some firebase event (except configuring the app).